# nohup executing with relative path

Tags: unix, ksh, nohup

I'm executing nohup like this:

```
nohup ./script.ksh &
```

Then when I send **SIGHUP** signal (Control-D) I exit the session and nohup **stops**.

If I execute like this:

```
nohup script.ksh &
```

Works fine...

Anybody can explain me why?

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior. By the way, what do you mean by exiting the session with Ctrl-C, normally it's Ctrl-D to quit a session, Ctrl-C will do nothing or I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, i meant Ctrl-D as you say

Comment: Then it's confirm, I can't reproduce this behavior on my systems, sorry.